# How do Argo CD track the resources it deploys?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

How do Argo CD track the resources it deploys? I see no label or annotation being put on the resources, or any other modification for that matter. So how do Argo CD determine which Kubernetes resources belongs to a certain Argo CD Application or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argo CD by default uses the label **app.kubernetes.io/instance** to track resources it creates, but it can also be configured to use a custom label and/or annotation.

See https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/resource_tracking/ for full details.